# creating database in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have installed mysql for python and running python from command line. I am getting syntax error while creating a database.

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> CREATE DATABASE chom;

  File "<stdin>", line 1

    CREATE DATABASE chom;
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 9):

`CREATE DATABASE chom;` this should be run from the MySQL command line client, not from the Python shell.

So, first type `mysql -u yourusername -p` from your command line. It will ask you for a password, type it in. Then you will get a prompt like this `mysql>`. Here is where you would type that query.

Now, if you want to do this through Python, you *can*, but it will require some more work.

```
>>> import MySQLdb as db
>>> con = db.connect(user="foo", passwd="secret")
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE chom;')
```

See [this guide](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/teaching/ap/examples/scripts_python_dbapi.pdf) for some examples on how to work with Python and MySQL using the standard DB API.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am getting the following error. Do i need to add Mysql path to environmental variables ? If so what path i need to add ? 

C:\>mysql -u Chom -p
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you install a MySQL server?

Comment: Technically creating the database is possible from python, "should be run from the MySQL command line client" is a subjective statement.

Comment: Can we use the same thing for an SQLite database using python ?

Comment: `username` is not input of `connect` function. please replace it with `user`

Answer (score 3):

If you want create a database,you can try:

```
import MySQLdb
db1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="****")
cursor = db1.cursor()
sql = 'CREATE DATABASE chom'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am getting the following error. <br/>

>>> db1 = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="Chom",passwd="")

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect

    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__

    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")

Comment: @chom Maybe you should check you mysql status.The username、password and port.Make sure your mysql service works well and can be connected with others.I think the error `"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)"` is caused by your mysql settings not python code.